# no accessible extension method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

The view is not able to get my GridData, not sure why.

The code pass the GridData in the view, but the view page is not able to access GridData object.

UserMaster Models:

```
namespace Project.Models
{
    public class UserMaster
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]

        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required]
    }

    public class UserMasterList
    {
        public List<UserMaster> GridData { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Control:

```
 UserMasterList userMasterList = new UserMasterList();
            List<UserMaster> gl = new List<UserMaster>();

            var userMasterListResult = _context.UserMaster.FromSql("EXECUTE [dbo].[UserMaster_Get] {0}", 0).ToList();

            foreach (var data in userMasterListResult)
            {
                gl.Add(data);
            }

            userMasterList.GridData = gl;
            return View(userMasterList);
```

View:

```
 @model Project.Models.UserMaster
           @foreach (var data in @Model.GridData)   {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => data.FirstName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => data.LastName)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
```

Error:
The code pass the GridData in the view, but the view page is not able to access GridData object.

Comment: Please add the relevant information from the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in view, you should have

```
@model Project.Models.UserMasterList
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you are passing an object with type of `UserMasterList`, but in your view, model is type of `UserMaster` so that you should update used `model` in view as like as below:

```
@model Project.Models.UserMasterList
```